# How to disable automatically build trigger in jenkins

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i have two or more service with seperate jenkinsfile in same github repo (same branch). Whenever I commit the code on github for particular services. Then I check  Jenkins job, unfortunately all Jenkins jobs triggered.

Could please help me out of this.

I tried to fix that issue, but I couldn't fine anything, I need whenever I push the commit for a particular service that jenkinsfile and Jenkins job only need to be triggered.

Comment: So I take it that all the jobs are set to trigger on commit?

Comment: Could you please describe the desired behaviour? It might make sense to add the relevant part of the directory structure of the repo and briefly describe which changes in which parts of the repo should trigger which pipeline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Eg: I have one repo name as welcome. Inside the repo I have two folders, one is A with Jenkinsfile and other folder is B with Jenkinsfile. Have a separate Jenkins job for both A and B. That welcome repo sets an automation that means whenever I update or modify those folders A or B it'll trigger automatically Jenkins job.            
If I update or modify something inside the A folder, it is triggered both A and B  Jenkins jobs also. So I want, whenever I update or modify the Respective folder (A or B) that particular Jenkins Job only need to be triggered. this is what i'm asking

Comment: Pls anyone can assist in this.